# UIImageView won't change size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cgrectmake

I am trying to alter the width and height of an UIImageView object but for some reason I can't.

This is the code I used:

```
-(void)setMenuImages
{ 
        self.menuImageButton.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"]; 
        self.menuImageButton.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,20,150); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The (UIImageView) menuImageButton is not created programmatically, but from storyboard interface with initial leading, trailing, width and height constraints.

Comment: create iboutlet of height and width constraint given to imageButton and then set constant value of each as per requirement.

Comment: How to declare constraints in header file please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `self. menuImageButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` in `viewDidLoad` and remove their constraints **or** you can add those constraints as `IBOutlets` and change them like

```
self.imageWidthConstraint.constant = 20;
self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 150;
```

**UPDATE**

To declare constraints in your header file you need to select those constrains and right click drag to the .h file as show in the gif

[image]

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints didn't work. How can I declare a constraint in a header file?

Comment: Check my updated answer @Student, btw `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` only works if you don't have any constraint added to your `UIImageView`

Comment: Thanks for your time mate. Have a nice day.